# PHP Regex Replace Number in String

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace a number in a string with another number by using regex. This should be super simple, but for some reason it's giving me grief today. "feed" in the string is dynamic and can contain letters or numbers only.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$new_number = 999;
$string = '/feed/page/1/?param=true';
preg_replace('/\/([0-9a-z])\/page\/([0-9])\/(.*)/i', '/$1/page/'.$new_number.'/$3', $string);
```

Should output: '/feed/page/999/?param=true'

Comment: As a side note, you can use other characters than `/` to delimit regex. `'@/([0-9a-z]+)/page/([0-9]+)/(.*)@i'` is sexier than `'/\/([0-9a-z]+)\/page\/([0-9]+)\/(.*)/i'`.

Comment: Thanks @DoubleGras! I had no idea about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forgetting the +'s, are you? :P  Try this as your regEx:

```
'/\/([0-9a-z]+)\/page\/([0-9]+)\/(.*)/i'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\/([0-9a-z]{1,})\/page\/([0-9]{1,})\/(.*)
```